# javascript setTimeout either not firing or firing with no wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, momentjs

I have a requirement that a html form must be submitted every 12 hours, or sooner.  If it is not, the page is to play an annoying sound.  The page will be displayed on a tablet mounted in a vehicle cabin and will use kiosk software to prevent leaving the page.

I am using **jQuery 3.1.1** and **moment.js**

```
<audio id="alarmSound">
    <source src="~/Sounds/railroad_crossing_bell.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="alarmSound1" />
    <source src="~/Sounds/railroad_crossing_bell.wav" type="audio/wav" id="alarmSound2" />
    <p class="error">Your browser does not support the &lt;audio&gt; tag</p>
</audio>
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
    //var targetDate = moment("@(LastSubmittedDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").add(12, 'hours').valueOf() - moment().valueOf();
    var targetDate = moment().add(2, "minutes");
    var timeToWait = targetDate.valueOf() - moment().valueOf();
    var timerVar;
    var audioVar = $("#alarmSound");
    $("#test").html("<dl><dt>targetDate</dt><dd>" + targetDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + "</dd><dt>timeToWait</dt><dd>" + timeToWait + "</dd></dd></dl>");

    console.log("configuring #alarmSound");
    $("#alarmSound").muted = false;
    $("#alarmSound").defaultMuted = false;
    $("#alarmSound").loop = true;
    $("#alarmSound").volume = 1.0;
    $("#alarmSound").controls = false;
    $("#alarmSound").preload = "auto";


    function alertFunc() {
        console.log("alertFunc() fired");
        $("#test").html("<p>alertFunc() Fired</p><dl><dt>targetDate</dt> <dd>" + targetDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + "</dd> <dt>timeToWait</dt> <dd>" + timeToWait + "</dd></dd ></dl >");
        $("#alarmSound").get(0).play();
    }

    function myTimeoutStopFunc() {
        console.log("myTimeoutStopFunc() fired");
        clearTimeout(timerVar);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("setTimeout(alertFunc, " + timeToWait + ")");
        timerVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, timeToWait);
    });
</script>


<div id="test2"><button name="timerStop" onclick="myTimeoutStopFunc()" >Stop Timer</button></div>
```

For testing I have it setting the time to now + a few minutes. Adding some console.log calls and fixing the number of seconds has helped.

It is currently working, but the audio stops after a few minutes.

Comment: The second argument to `setTimeout` is a delay to *wait* (in ms), not a time at which to execute. If you want to wait 5 minutes from when the page loads, simply use `setTimeout(alertFunc, 300000)`

Comment: Of course, you'll have to do something else about `timeToWait.format(...` as it is a `Number` but I think you may have ran into this problem sooner or later anyway

Comment: so my value would be `timeToWait = moment().add(5, "minutes").valueOf() - moment.valueOf;`?

Comment: and the format is only called when displaying debug info

Comment: Why bother? 5 minutes is 300,000ms and with `setTimeout`, we're only ever talking about fixed units of elapsed time

Comment: Also, if you calculate the delay using `(now + 5 minutes) - now`, you may run into problems over daylight savings boundaries

Comment: Because I am waiting till valueFromDatabase + 12 hrs

Comment: In that case, then yes; you should calculate the time to wait (in `ms`) from now to `valueFromDatabase + 12 hours`

Comment: @phil if you create an actual answer I'll accept and close :)

Answer (score 0):

With Phil posting only in comments I was unable to give him the answer.  I calculate the difference from database time value to now using milliseconds and add that value.  Works great.